# C : Write char array (containing '1' and '0') into as binary in a file

Tags: c, arrays, file, binary, fwrite

I'm having troubles writing char arrays of '1' and '0' 's as binary in a file.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to do :

```
int main(){
  FILE * file;
  file = fopen("file" , "w+b");

  char buffer[8] = "11001100"; // 8 bits-> 1 byte to write

  fwrite(buffer,1,8,file);

  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is it writes itself as text in my file (8 bytes written), not as binary/just 1 byte.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The standard library does not know what you are trying to achieve and will not magically pack/convert your sequence of characters into a byte. You will have to convert it into one byte of data manually, before you even attempt to write it. Afterwards, you can simply write that byte into a file using `fwrite`.

Comment: You could explore `strtoul` which converts a string to a value, with the number base of the string characters. Then write the converted value to an output file.

Comment: ... Just remember that to use `strtoul` you will have to add a zero-terminator character to your sequence. At this time it is not a string - it has no zero-terminator at the end.

Comment: I suspect that you will have to write some code to iterate the chars and OR a mask into an output byte.  If you start at the first char, that will be the msb, and so you can start the mask as 0x80.  If the char is '1', OR in the mask.  Shift the mask right as you iterate the chars.

Comment: Cceck the source of the character string of 0/1. I suspect that where that is coming from you will find the desired 1byte representation already available.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I'm having troubles figuring out how to write a manually write a byte. People tend to use `unsigned char` as a byte. But can you use << with it ?

Comment: Please ask another question about that. Generally, shift `unsigned` types.

Comment: `'0'` and `'1'` are quite different than `0` and `1`. You have 8 bytes in your string,, not 1 byte of 8 bits. if you change that to `unsigned char c = 0xcc;` then you will have 8 bits as `0b11001100`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to convert the string containing a binary number as ASCII into a byte. You can do this your own or simply with `strtol()`:

```
char *buffer = "11001100"; // 8 chars
char *behind;
char byte = (char)strtol(buffer, &behind, 2); // Base 2 for a binary number

fwrite(&byte,1,1,file); // 1 element with 1 byte ach
```

Comment: No `nul` terminator, as commented.

Comment: There is a `nul`, but the buffer is declared wrong.

Comment: Nope, you restrict the string length to 8. `char buffer[] = "11001100";`

Comment: I'm not sure the OP need this answer.

Comment: Yeah well you slyly changed the code. It was wrong.

Comment: Yes, as I said. So it isn't slyly. It is explicitly mentioned. I c&p'ed it from the Q.

Comment: @Stargateur Why not?

Comment: Because it side-stepped the OP's mistake when challenged, instead of correcting the mistake.

Comment: The OP did a mistake and still have a unsolved problem, he asked for. I showed the solution and fixed the mistake.

Comment: No, you side-stepped the mistake `char buffer[8] = "11001100";` instead of pointing out what the mistake was.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad In my opinion OP does't understand basic C, you propose a solution that overflow a `char` if `11001100` exceed `CHAR_MAX` (this is the case on 99% of implementation) and it's undefined behavior. Why not explain to the OP the difference between bytes and bits ?

Comment: No, I fixed it as announced. BTW: The problem with this is *not* the size.

Comment: @Stargateur In my opinion, the OP does know the differences between bits and bytes. However, I explained in my answer, that he has an ASCII string with numbers and has to convert it into a byte.

Comment: I understand I have 8 bytes in my string, but I have no idea how I'm supposed to convert it into a byte, and then write it in my file. I'm trying to convert it manually using masks btw.

Comment: Exactly. And `strtol()` converts the 8-byte string into a number. So I think, it is exactly, what you are looking for. (BTW: You have 9 bytes in your "string",  because in C strings are terminated with `\0`, an additional character.)

Comment: No, there are only 8 bytes in `char buffer[8] = "11001100";` which lacks the `nul` string terminator. Do follow the comments and get up to speed.

Comment: There are 9 bytes in `"11001100"`. Maybe you should read what you are answering to.

Comment: Nope, there are only 8 bytes in `char buffer[8] = "11001100";`. Look at the `[8]`.

Comment: Nope, there are 9 bytes in `"11001100"`. There is a \0 terminator in "11001100". I looked at the 8. Please, read my comment before answering to it.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I'm still going to try to do it manually, I'm not sure if I fully understand how strtol works

Comment: OMG there might be 9 in *your* version, but there are only 8 in the OP's code. As I said, you have not addressed this.

Comment: nope, in the code of the OP there are 9 bytes in ˙"11001100"`, too. This is because of what we call the C standard.

Comment: @AnthonyMorel An implementation can simply have a storage for a byte, which is 0 at the beginning. Then you loop through the string from left to right, shift the storage on bit up using << and or-in a 1 for a '1' inside the loop.

Comment: `char buffer[8] = "11001100";` is not terminated with `'\0'`,, and if it was that would be UB for exceeding the bounds of the array. `char buffer[9] = "11001100";` is terminated with `'\0'`

Comment: `char buffer[8] = "11001100"` is no expression, so it is meaningless to talk about how this non-expression is terminated. It cannot be terminated or non-terminated, because it is no value. "11001100" is an expression and 0-terminated (precise: is a pointer to a0-terminated string.) This is really basic C standard.

Comment: I managed to do it manually like this : `int b = 0x0;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 8;i++){
    int mask = buffer[i] == '1' ? 1 : 0;
    b = b << 1 | pass;
  }`

Comment: `mask` is `pass`? But this is the approach, yes. (Hey, you do not understand the difference between bits and bytes. How could you do that?)

Comment: Yes, sorry mask is pass . I know the difference between bits and bytes. (1 byte is composed of 8 bits). I just didn't know I could edit a my int like this

Comment: *I* know, that you know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `0b` prefix i think...
[GNU doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html)

`0b` says you are writing a byte.

If you write somethink like this:

```
int main(){
  FILE * file;
  file = fopen("file" , "w+b");
  char c;

  c = 0b11001100

  fwrite(&c,1,1,file);

  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```